# Nginx redirect using part of last_path_component

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect, substring

I am redirecting from domain1 to domain2 based on what's present in the URI, but I need to pass to domain2 only the first part of the last path component.

The main entry point to be redirected would be:

https://www.domain1.com/us/type-a-products/**9011-HWD-bolts-new**

new end point:

https://www.domain2.com/us-us/type-a-products/**9011**

So I need to consider only the first part of the last past component before the first hypen (basically the product code).

The redirect is easy to do:

```
 if ($request_uri ~* "([^/]*$)" ) {
   set  $last_path_component  $1;
 }
```

```
 location ~ /us/type-a-products/(.*) {
     return 301 https://www.domain2.com/us-us/type-a-products/$1;
 }
```

But how can I consider only the first part of the last path component (tried different regexs but I only managed to extract the word after the last hyphen).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A good place to do this is in a map.
It happens early in the nginx cycle and will not short circuit the flow of your config by
[introducing regex locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWRYbLKsS0I).

outside of the server config

```
map $uri $redirect_id_uri {
    ~^/us/type-a-products/\*\*(?<id>\d+)-.*\*\*$ https://www.domain2.com/us/type-a-products/**$id**;
}
```

inside server config

```
if ($redirect_id_uri) {
    return 301 $redirect_id_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cole, I didn't think of using map straight through, this also does the job

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
([^/-]+)[^/]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vc54Lp/1). *Details*:

- `([^/-]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `/` and `-`
- `[^/]*` - any zero or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, works good, I made a mistake with the rewrite intially and it wasn't working